# What wrong with OMP APIs?

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, libgomp

Sorry again for my ignorance, I want to run #include <omp.h> for the #pragma omp parallel for command.
As it didn't work for me I checked my gcc version and it is 5.1.0, I added the libgomp.a and libgomp.spec files to the mingw lib folder. From codeblocks-> settings-> compiler I added -fopenmp
on other compiler options and -lgomp -pthread on other linker options as suggested by any online guide.
Result: "undefined reference to GOMP_parallel",
"undefined reference to omp_get_num_threads" and "undefined reference to omp_get_thread_num".
I'm on windows 10 and running codeblocks for c ++.

Comment: Which version of GOMP are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC 5.1.0 is extremely old!

Use a newer GCC (current is 12.1.0) with MinGW-w64 (instead of MinGW, which is also very old).

There is a standalone package available for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows at https://winlibs.com/ and the site also explains how to configure [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/) to use it.